# Eventhandlers, new click event executed in scope of previous click event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent, dom-events

Tough title to explain the situation but I will share the context. I have a dropdown that is opened, and upon opening I set a new handler to check if the user clicked outside of the boundaries of the dropdown. Once that interaction happens, we can close the dropdown. I have enclosed a very simple test case, be aware that business logic for actually checking for dropdown boundaries is missing for demonstration purposes.

The observation is that the `eventlistener` for click, added after executing the earlier click event for opening the dropdown, is executed immediately as well. I would have expected that, considering the `mousedown` event has already been executed this event listener would only be executed on new click events.

This can be further validated; if I add a timeout on adding the eventhandler, it works just fine. Any thoughts or smart ideas on this approach?

I added a complete test case that shows the challenge. Both approaches available in the Open method.

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<a class="trigger" activates="A">Open Dropdown</a>
<div id="A">Dropdown contents</div>

<script>

function Dropdown(domEl){
    this.trigger = domEl;
    this.Init();
}
Dropdown.prototype = {
    Init : function(){  
        console.log('initialized dropdown');
        this.trigger.addEventListener('click',function(){this.Open()}.bind(this));
    },
    Open : function(){  
        console.log('opened dropdown');
        // this does not work, as the click event is triggered immediately upon triggering the Open even set under Init
        window.addEventListener('click',function(){this.OnOpenEventHandler()}.bind(this));
        
        // this works, as the event is not triggered immediately
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.addEventListener('click',function(){this.OnOpenEventHandler()}.bind(this));
        }.bind(this),50);
    },
    OnOpenEventHandler : function(){
        console.log('dropdown can be closed');
        this.Close();
    },
    Close : function(){
        console.log('closed dropdown');
    }
}

var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
triggers.forEach((el,i) => {
    new Dropdown(el);
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `stopPropagation()`, as per your comment, an alternative solution might be checking that the click event has not been fired by the `trigger` element:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <a class="trigger" activates="A">Open Dropdown</a>
  <div id="A">Dropdown contents</div>

  <script>
    function Dropdown(domEl) {
      this.trigger = domEl;
      this.Init();
    }
    Dropdown.prototype = {
      Init: function() {
        console.log('initialized dropdown');
        this.trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
          this.Open()
        }.bind(this));
      },
      Open: function() {
        console.log('opened dropdown');

        window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          /* 
           * execute the code only if the click event
           * has not been fired by the 'a.trigger' element
           */
          if (event.srcElement != this.trigger) {
            this.OnOpenEventHandler()
          }
        }.bind(this));
      },
      OnOpenEventHandler: function() {
        console.log('dropdown can be closed');
        this.Close();
      },
      Close: function() {
        console.log('closed dropdown');
      }
    }

    var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
    triggers.forEach((el, i) => {
      new Dropdown(el);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, I think you simply need to prevent the click event from propagating:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <a class="trigger" activates="A">Open Dropdown</a>
  <div id="A">Dropdown contents</div>

  <script>
    function Dropdown(domEl) {
      this.trigger = domEl;
      this.Init();
    }
    Dropdown.prototype = {
      Init: function() {
        console.log('initialized dropdown');
        this.trigger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation(); // will prevent the click event from propagating
          this.Open()
        }.bind(this));
      },
      Open: function() {
        console.log('opened dropdown');
        // this does not work, as the click event is triggered immediately upon triggering the Open even set under Init
        window.addEventListener('click', function() {
          this.OnOpenEventHandler()
        }.bind(this));

        // this works, as the event is not triggered immediately
        /*window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.addEventListener('click',function(){this.OnOpenEventHandler()}.bind(this));
        }.bind(this),50);*/
      },
      OnOpenEventHandler: function() {
        console.log('dropdown can be closed');
        this.Close();
      },
      Close: function() {
        console.log('closed dropdown');
      }
    }

    var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
    triggers.forEach((el, i) => {
      new Dropdown(el);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not necesarilly. 


Stopping propagation actually prevents the event for bubbling (be default up) while there actually might be other events impacted.

What I do expect though, is that the click event, which is added as a result from an earlier click event is not executed immediately. This is a complete block of event bubbling, while I just want the second click event to behave.


In a way it should not even happen, because the mousedown event has happened in the first click event, and not in the second click event.